# Is it possible to have a textbox in which they input information to be searched in the column that they can also choose by use of a drop down menu?

Tags: mysql

For example, user wants to search the movie database, by director's last name, so the user will type in Smith and then in the drop down menu will choose Director's Last Name. I just need to know how to get the post variables into the SELECT --> WHERE function

```
$columnsch = $_POST["columnsearch"]; 
$contentsch = $_POST["contentsearch"];

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE $columnsch ='$contentsch'");
if (!$result) {
    die ("Database Query Failed: ".mysql_error());
```

I know the above code is incorrect but it gives the general idea of what I want to achieve.
Zdravko, Im really new to this, Im not sure where your lines of code for example the sql would fit in with what I have.

Answer (score 0):

you can do 2 things: first is to generate the sql based on the search criteria:

```
sql = sql + 'WHERE ' + SearchField + ' = "'+ SearchValue + '";'
```

the other is to write sql like this:

```
 WHERE (@SearchField = 'Director' and Ditector = @SearchValue)
 OR (@SerarchField = 'Star' and Star = @SearchValue)
 ....
```